# How to swap the values in two columns in R?

Tags: r, vector, multiple-columns, swap

```
V1    V2
 5     6
 4     4
 2     5
```

How would I swap the values in these two column vectors. So that the outcome would be:

```
V1    V2
 6     5
 4     4
 5     2
```

Comment: You can rename columns with `colnames(x) <- c("V2", "V1")`

Comment: @akash87 Is there a way to do this without changing the names, but just swapping the values?

Comment: once renamed i believe the op needs to reorder them to comply with the expected output. `x <- x[rev(colnames(x))]`

Comment: @agenis Do I input the column names again? inside of colnames(x)?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't accept renaming the columns, especially when you have great tools like "rename_at" in the dplyr package, that even accept regular expression (i believe your actual data is a bit more complex that V1 and V2...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this:

```
tmp <- df[1]
df[1] <- df[2]
df[2] <- tmp
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is probably:

```
df[1:2] <- df[2:1]
```

That is, it swaps the values but not the column names.

More programmatically:

```
c2swap <- c("V1", "V2")
df[c2swap] <- df[rev(c2swap)]
```

Comment: Wow, this is working perfectly, apparently, I have been trying to use if_else but it does not behave as expected! But your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I work with `data.table`, say, `dt`. In my case,

```
dt[1:2] <- dt[2:1]
```

swaps the first and second rows, while

```
dt[,1:2] <- dt[,2:1]
```

swaps the values of the first and second columns leaving the same names.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example (including loading `data.table`, etc.)?